# React Rendering Different Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state, web-deployment

Let's say I'm building a react application that changes content inside a box with a button click in this manner(Clicking the same button):

```
Click 1: Component 1
Click 2: Component 2
Click 3: Component 3
Click 4: Component 1
Click 5: Component 2
Click 6: Component 3
```

So the obvious way to do this would be via states, and in the render method render the component you wish according to what the state is. But I don't wish to rerender every component. That is, on the button click, I just want the previous component to become invisible, and display the new element.

This is easy to do in simple normal HTML/CSS/JS:

```
display:none;
```

But how would one approach this in react, and why would it be better/more efficient than just doing it normally?

Not necessarily looking for full code, more of an understanding of what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: click 2 means click of button 2 or twice click on same button ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Twice click of the same button. There is only button, sorry for the confusion. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Maintain a counter as an state and increment it on every click, based on that router you can conditionally add styles to your component eg `onClick={() => {this.setState((prevState) => ({counter: (prevState.counter + 1)%3)}))}}` and then in the component style which you need to apply internally on component outermost div `<Component1 style={(this.state.counter ==  0)? {display: 'block'}: {display: 'none'}}/>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri But why should I use React for this, does doing this with react make the operation more efficient? Also, if you wish, you can also put your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: What I would do generally is not have all the components loaded and hide them but render them conditionally and yes I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a counter as an state and increment it on every click, based on that value you can conditionally add styles to your component eg

```
 onClick={() => {
     this.setState((prevState) => (
            {counter: (prevState.counter + 1)%3)}
             )
    )}
 }
```

and then in the component style which you need to apply internally on component outermost div

```
<Component1 style={(this.state.counter == 0)? {display: 'block'}: {display: 'none'}}/>
```

And in Component1

```
render() {
    return <div style={this.props.style}>{/* Content Here */}</div>
}
```

Also since React maintains a Virtual DOM for updates, it is more efficeint and fast in rendering contents

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any explanations...

```js
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  getContainer() {
    switch (this.props.id) {
      case 1:
        return (<div>First Container</div>);
      case 2:
        return (<div>Second Container</div>);
      case 3:
        return (<div>Third Container</div>);
      case 4:
        return (<div>4th Container</div>);
      case 5:
        return (<div>5th Container</div>);
      case 6:
        return (<div>6th Container</div>);
      case 7:
        return (<div>7th Container</div>);
      case 8:
        return (<div>8th Container</div>);
      default:
        return (<div>don't have a Container</div>);
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.getContainer()}
      </div>
      );
  }
};

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 1
    };
    this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  
  test() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.test}> click me {this.state.count}</button>
        <Container id={this.state.count}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question of OP, since he asked for a solution without rerendering the components. He just want's to hide the components that shouldn't be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use state and cycle a counter between 1 and 6 and use a counter as you're imagining. Simple logic in the render function, or a subsequent sub-component can map to the 6 display components you want to show.

Since react diffs their shadow DOM to minimizes changes on re-render, you'll typically save a good deal of render overhead while creating more expressive code compared to changing HTML tag displays or classes.

Looking at the bigger picture, I'd say put it together in React using the design patterns you see in the documentation and don't worry about further optimization unless/until you run into a problem. Usually your render bottleneck will be a badly written recurring function, not React's re-rendering of components.

Edit:

I'd like to add that you can still target HTML elements by the available HTML/CSS/JS attributes by adding onClick attributes to your React render elements that call a function defined in the React class. In this way, you could still change your display or class attributes while keeping the other benefits of the React library and general design pattern. I've used this to start autofocus on a component or other functions in the past. In the case of rendering a component, I still suggest you trust React's optimizations unless/until the give you a reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to accomplish this in React without managing state and rerendering. If you wanted to render all but one of the slides with `display: none` you'd have to manage state somewhere, and rerender the component with the new style when it changes.

A central part of React's paradigm is its declarative approach. This means that components, with the same properties and state, will *always* render the same view. What you are asking for is

1) a component that will render different views for the same props/state

OR

2) access the DOM from inside a React component and change the style of an element

Neither approach is viable in React, and by design.

As far as whether or not this makes sense to build in React, there's not a straightforward answer for that. If you're wanting just a static carousel and some other static content, then probably vanilla JS or jQuery are valid options. If you're wanting to build a dynamic carousel that calls a server-side API to populate content from a CMS or trying to build a reusable component that can be integrated into various parts of your app, then React is probably the way to go.